# What is fastest, rendering on a CPU or a GPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance, hardware

For Christmas my parents gave me a new graphic card. Even though I got a new card (R9 390), the rendering times are really slow.
I am asking if I should get another card instead or perhaps its better to get another CPU like i7 5820k. Right now I have a i7 4771.

When I have saved some more money I could buy a better processor, but perhaps its better to sell the graphic card and buy another card instead? Perhaps a gtx 980ti? I am 12 years old, so  I dont want to waste my money.

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest rendering"?  The actual rendertime of a given scene depends on vastly more things than the actual hardware.  Things such as scene size, shader complexity, and poly count (as well as dozens and dozens of other factors) all play into rendertimes.

Comment: Im rendering 1080p animations low poly

Comment: There are literally hundreds of factors that affect rendertimes, and even if you knew most of the major factors it would be virtually impossible to say "it will take `X` hours to render without actually rendering it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general hardware benchmarks and not about compatibility and use with Blender specifically.

Comment: i7-5820k takes 2 minutes and 29 seconds to render the BMW test scene, the GTX 980Ti takes 1 minute 28 seconds. There's your answer

Comment: @Jerryno Assuming he wants to use the Cycles engine and the scene fits on the 6GB of Vram the 980ti has.

Comment: For questions like this please go to http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support . The forum format is better suited for this kind of discussions. Else the answers generated here are mostly opinion based

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about general hardware benchmarks and not about compatibility and use with Blender specifically.

Answer (score 4):

**Rendering is an *extremely* complicated process**, thus the actual rendertime of a given scene depends on vastly more things than the actual hardware. Things such as scene size, shader complexity, and poly count (as well as dozens and dozens of other factors) all play into rendertimes.

Since there are literally hundreds of factors that affect rendertimes, it's really impossible to say how long a given scene would take to render.  Even if you knew all of the major factors it would still be virtually impossible to quantify these and say "it will take X hours to render, without actually rendering it.

---

That said, you can somewhat accurately generically compare the *relative* speed between two pieces of hardware.  So *most of the time* the gtx980ti will be considerably faster than most any CPU.

*That* said, I'd say save your money for now.  Your current specs are pretty darn fast, rendering is just a complicated process and will take time no matter what your specs are.  In the future I'd probably upgrade the GPU to an NVIDIA, but it won't be massively faster (unless you go for a Titan or m6000 or something like that). Compare your times to [this article](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/proof-that-cycles-is-getting-faster-speed-comparisons/), it's a year old but still fairly relevant.

You may also want to consider going for two less powerful GPUs (provided your motherboard is SLI capable) and getting them one at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure he's asking how long something takes to render. I think he's asking which is faster: 980Ti or 5820k.

Comment: @meed96  That's what I thought initially, but [he indicated](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45346/what-is-fastest-rendering-on-a-prosoccer-or-a-graphic-card/45357?noredirect=1#comment76567_45346) that [my](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45346/what-is-fastest-rendering-on-a-prosoccer-or-a-graphic-card/45357?noredirect=1#comment76560_45346) [comments](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45346/what-is-fastest-rendering-on-a-prosoccer-or-a-graphic-card/45357?noredirect=1#comment76565_45346) answered his question, so I converted them into a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, For Christmas I got a new graphic card as I started  doing Blender 3 month back. I am mostly doing star wars and scenic animations. Even though I got a new card (R9 390), the rendering times are really slow. I am asking if I should get another card instead or perhaps its better to get another CPU like i7 5820k. Right now I have a i7 4771.
When I have saved some more money I could buy a better processer, but perhaps its better to sell the graphic card and buy another card instead? Perhaps a gtx 980ti? . I am 12 years old, so  I dont want to vaste my money.

Comment: @SørenGang Yeah don't waste money for CPU when you have one, but invest in CUDA cards. Instead of one 980Ti you can get two older gtx780 6GB, one is not that much slower so with both you get like 1.5x the power of single 980Ti 6GB. You will get bigger electric bill but that is not your concern I suppose. I wish I had that much money as you do in your age.

Comment: @SørenGang  The GPU would probably be quite a bit faster than the CPU.  I got along just fine rendering with my i7-4770 before I got a GPU.  Jerryno's sugestion is pretty good though if you're looking to upgrade your card.  That said, even though it isn't CUDA an R9 390 is pretty fast (I have a friend with one).

Comment: @SørenGang  I'd say save your money for now, your specs are pretty darn fast, rendering is just a complicated and slow process so it will take time no matter what your specs are.  In the future I'd probably upgrade the GPU to an NVIDIA, but it won't be extremely faster.  Compare your times to [this article](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/proof-that-cycles-is-getting-faster-speed-comparisons/), it's a year old but still fairly relevant.

Comment: @Jerryno Bigger electric bill? I don't think it'll barely be noticeable: http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/computers.html

Comment: @meed96  I think he was partially joking.  But that article *is* a few years old, stuff takes more electricity these days.  My GPU alone uses 120 watts!  And my (relatively modest) PSU gives up to 650 watts (given I am sure not all of it is being utilized).

Comment: @PGmath It might be old but I don't think computer hardware power requirements have really moved much. They're making stuff more powerful, but they're also decreasing the amount of power required. Three years isn't going to drastically change the numbers listed there. But your card using 120watts is presumably only when it's at maximum draw, and not all the time.

Comment: guys... take this to chat!

Answer (score 0):

Just updated my 5 year Mac to a PC, i7 7800x with a single NVIDIA ROG Strix GeForce GTX 1080 TI OC.

**Test:**
For a given scene rendering for Print (5000 x 5000px) in cycles and with high poly and hair particles...
GPU rendering was marginally faster than my late 2012 Mac (4 threads).
CPU rendering (12 threads) was significantly faster at over three times the speed.

**Results:** (approx. values)
**Mac** render 1 hour & 45 minutes.
**GPU** render 1 hour 20 minutes.
**CPU** rendering 35 minutes.

**Disclaimer:**

- This was a single render test.
- There is a chance the PC and/or GPU was not optimised for Blender
  cycles render.

**Conclusion:**
In this test though the factor was thread count.

There is also a chance that SLI could significantly speed up GPU renders to compete with the CPU.

In my experience the GPU is optimised for calculating and displaying particular graphics quickly ie. low poly, normal mapping, simple particle arrays, physics, shadows (which is always hard to do in real time), shading - post processing effects. Most effects we see in games such as caustics are usually faked using shading or texturing and not often calculated in real time.

For the price of an Intel Core i9 7900X, which is comparable to the price of my GPU I could have got another 8 threads at 20 threads, and use the money I spent on the 7800x to buy a lesser GPU.